# "On" vs. "at" vs. "to" in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> Please write to me **on/at/to** this address.

I think *at* would be more apt. But I'm not sure. My friend told me *to*. Please correct my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are over 600 written instances where ["**please write to me**" and "**this address**"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22please%20write%20to%20me%22%20%22this%20address%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) both occur in close proximity. I expect in every case the intervening preposition will be **at**.

That's because *at* is the "standard" [preposition of place / location](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-place.htm) for a "point" location (others include *in* for an "enclosed space", and *on* for a "surface").

An *address* is a location, but it's not normally thought of as being *in* an enclosed space, or *on* a surface. There are exceptions, though - for example...

> Don't send it to my New York office, because I'll be in England. My address **in** London is [blah blah].

Comment: "I expect in every case the intervening preposition will be _to_." Really? _to_? or _at_?

Comment: @J.R.: Ooops! I originally typed ***at**, not **on** or **to*** (must've had a brain fart while deleting superfluous text! :)